# Node.js update via GitHub

Tags: node.js, github, discord

So I am currently using node.js to make a Discord bot. I am switching the way things work however. The bot runs from my machine (computer), but I would like my friends to be able to work on it as well. Is there any way we can clone a GitHub repo into an existing folder, as to update the current BOT.js file we have?

The point of this is to have the bot auto update via github

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty Github repository, make sure to create it without any readme etc before you have made your first push.

Then using git, you initialize a git repo inside your current folder you are working out of, when you have done that, you can set a upstream to Github (w/ the repository URL you got for your newly created repository (on Github)), then just commit your files, push them to the Github repo master branch and you should be good to go.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Wouldn't that be to update code from the bot to the github? I want to download from the GitHub to the bot

Comment: You cannot pull from a repo into a non-repo folder. You need to have an instance of git in the folder you want to update from the git repo.

Comment: A bit confused (relatively new to git). I created a new git in the folder, I added the upstream, added all my files to the new repo, and i try to clone (using nodegit) and I get this error:

`{ Error: '../*****-Bot' exists and is not an empty directory
    at Error (native) errno: -4 }`

Comment: Your github repo is not empty. It needs to set an upstream to an empty repo.